# Can do rank over partition in SQL, how to do in LINQ to xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

> ```
> <Entities>
>     <Request> 
>        <ID> A1 </ID> <!-- Can be multiple records with same values -->
>        <Finance>
>           <StartDate> Some Date </StartDate> <!-- Unique per ID -->
>        </Finance>
>     <Request>
>     <Request> ... </Request>
> </Entities>
> ```

There can be multiple requests with same ID but in such cases, the StartDate needs to be different per Request.

I need to take out the latest two dates per ID.

If this were an SQL table with ID and StartDate columns, I'd use the following query which is working fine:

```
SELECT ID, StartDate 
FROM ( SELECT ID, StartDate, RANK() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) rank
       FROM Request ) 
WHERE rank IN ('1','2')
```

But I have the data in XML format and the best I could come up with was ordering the data according to ID, StartDate. I still need to dug out latest two dates for every ID there is.

> var cafrequests =
>
> ```
> from request in xdoc.Descendants("Request")
> orderby (int)request.Element("ID"), 
> (DateTime)request.Element("Finance").Element("StartDate") ascending
> select new
> {
>     ID = request.Element("ID"),
>     StartDate = request.Element("Finance").Element("StartDate"),
> };
> ```

Using Take(2) would only fetch me the top 2 lines of data, not top 2 per ID.

So can anybody tell me what is the equivalent of the above SQL statement in LINQ? I don't want to parse and manage XML using loops and conditionals in C# and I'm quite new to LINQ (read about it yesterday and started using it) and I'm still going through the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, I tested it:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Data.xml");

        var result2 = doc.Element("Entities")
            .Elements("Request")
            .GroupBy(key => key.Element("ID").Value, el => DateTime.Parse(el.Element("Finance").Element("StartDate").Value))
            .Select(el =>
                new
                {
                    id = el.Key,
                    max2 = el.OrderByDescending(date => date).Take(2)
                });
```

- `doc.Element("Entities")` - gets element named Entity which is a root element of the document, another way of retrieving this element would be `doc.Root`
- `Elements("Request")` - gets elements named Request that are children of Entity
- `GroupBy` - is a method somewhat similar to `GROUP BY` in SQL, first parameter is element that is going to be used for grouping, it is a child of a Request element, second parameter is an element selector function that parses `DateTime` from StartDate element (which is a child of Finance element which is a child of Request element)
- `.Select(el => new...)` - method that creates anonymous type that holds ID and 2 records that have highest dates for ID

Here is a query that gets the same result, but written in an query syntax (example above is method syntax):

```
        var result = from el in doc.Root.Elements("Request")
                     group DateTime.Parse(el.Element("Finance").Element("StartDate").Value) by el.Element("ID").Value into grouped
                     select new { 
                         id = grouped.Key,
                         max2 = (from el in grouped
                                 orderby el descending
                                 select el)
                                 .Take(2)
                     };
```

Comment: Though I don't understand whole of this code, it does work. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help. I added some explanations and an example written in query syntax, maybe it clarifies what's going on in the query :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't we Group by Id and pick the recent dates ? Something like this. If you are getting list of Ids and corresponding Dates in the result set (cafrequests)

```
var result = cafrequests.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x=>new{ x.Key,Dates = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.StartDate).Select(y=>y.StartDate).Take(2)}).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key);
```

This will give you the top 2 dates for each Id.